# How is a "positive question record" calculated?

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

For the badges Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic, you need to ask varying numbers of well-received questions on different days. You also need to maintain a "positive question record"

On Stack Overflow, I have enough well received questions for the Curious badge, and am almost there on Math SE. However, on both of these sites, I fail the positive question record requirement. On both sites, I have cumulative question scores well above 0, (On Math SE, 85, and on Stack Overflow, 37), yet I don't have "positive question records".

This raises the question, how is a "positive question record" calculated?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) explains the criteria:

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is
>
> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5
>
> Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

Since a downvoted, closed and deleted question counts against you three times it only takes a few to seriously skew the results, so I would guess you probably have a few deleted questions.

Comment: On MATH SE, I believe I have one closed question, and two negative questions, but I don't believe I have any deleted questions, Is there an easy way to find out?

Comment: You can look at the "deleted recent questions" link on your profile question list, but that only lists questions that are < 60 days old, anything older than that you can't see (unless you have a direct link or can search a cached version of your profile page maybe)

Comment: You have 3 closed question on math (duplicates count as being closed), that still shouldn't put you below the 0.5 needed though so you probably have an old deleted question

Comment: I was just doing the calculations. My Math SE account is less than 2 months old, and I came up with a 0.666..., so either there's a bug, or my account is much older than I thought

Comment: Looks like it works out as `(15 - 2 - 3) / 15 = 0.666` a single downvoted deleted question would put that under the .5 needed, did you check if you have any recent deleted questions?

Comment: Yeah, I checked, there's none that I can see, which is why I say my account might be older than I thought.

Comment: Your profile there says "Member for 2 years", you probably have an old deleted question you forgot about

Comment: I have some comments from February last year, it's not impossible I deleted a question, so that's almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Don't forget that negatively scored closed questions with no positively scoring answers are auto-deleted after (i believe) 30 days, so you didn't need to have deleted them yourself.