# Does a "Positive question record" count across the whole SE network?

Tags: support, badge-progress

So, I've been reading up on the [curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated). I get the formula, but I have a question about it, because of reasons described below.

I just joined SCI-FI. I asked a question that got 4 upvotes (at the time of this writing). It was my best received question yet. It got me looking at the "curious" badge, and I still have 0 days (which makes sense to me), but I noticed I still "need a positive question record". This confuses me because I only have 1 positive question asked on that site, which to me says my question record should be positive. The only reason I can think of is if the rest of the network is counting against me, but is that possible? If not, what else could be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, badge progress is limited to the site you're tracking a badge on.

You don't yet have a positive question record because your question record is just as cached as the rest of the progress. As well, it's not a new day yet, and the badge calculation only looks at questions up to the day before today. As far as that particular badge, your current number of questions is still 0, and you can't say you have a positive question record over 0 questions.

Once your badge progress updates tomorrow, you'll have one question towards the badge and a positive question record.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I should have thought of that.